# Oracle xmlTransform returns SQL Error [6502] [65000]: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle

I have an XML stored in a table and an XSL stored in another table both as XMLTYPE datatypes. I am using Oracle's xmlTransform stored procedure to transform the XML to HTML content and when I execute xmltransform(xml,xsl) I get the error below:

````
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 169```

Where could I be possibly going wrong?
````

Comment: Are you trying to store the output in a VARCHAR2 variable? The output is probably more than 4000 characters, so you should either store it in an XMLTYPE variable or a CLOB.

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing that out. Yes using getClobVal() solved the issue.